# Rendering only to a part of a texture

Tags: opengl-es, framebuffer

Can I bind a 2000x2000 texture to a color attachment in a FBO, and tell OpenGL to behave exactly as if the texture was smaller, let's say 1000x1000?

The point is, in my rendering cycle I need many (mostly small) intermediate textures to render to, but I need only 1 at a time. I am thinking that, rather than creating many smaller textures, I will have only 1 appropriately large, and I will bind it to an FBO at hand, tell OpenGL to render only to part of it, and save memory.

Or maybe I should be destroying/recreating those textures many times per frame? That would certainly save even more memory, but wouldn't that cause a noticeable slowdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I bind a 2000x2000 texture to a color attachment in a FBO, and
>   tell OpenGL to behave exactly as if the texture was smaller, let's say
>   1000x1000?

Yes, just set `glViewport()` to the region you want to render to, and remember to adjust `glScissor()` bounding regions if you are ever enabling scissor testing.

> Or maybe I should be destroying/recreating those textures many times
>   per frame? That would certainly save even more memory, but wouldn't
>   that cause a noticeable slowdown?

Completely destroying and recreating a new texture object every frame will be slow because it will cause constant memory reallocation overhead, so definitely don't do that.

Having a pool of pre-allocated textures which you cycle though is fine though - that's a pretty common technique. You won't really save much in terms of memory storing a 2K*2K texture vs storing 4 separate 1K*1K textures - the total storage requirement is the same and the additional metadata overhead is tiny in comparison - so if keeping them separate is easier in terms of application logic I'd suggest doing that.

Comment: I never use the Scissor test. So then the only thing I should be doing is a call to glVieport()? Hmm, I;'ve tried that already and I am getting wrong results, but maybe I am doing something wrong....

Comment: Yes, if you never use scissor then you shouldn't need to worry. Remember any user of that merged texture later will have to use adjusted texture coordinates.

Comment: I have very many smaller textures, using only one of size (max width)x(max height) saves a lot....

Comment: Well, yeah, of course, it does work with a simple glViewport(), there was a naive omission on my part when I tried it the first time. Sometimes you just need someone knowledgeable tell you a given thing should be working :)

Comment: =) Glad you got it sorted.